# How to instantiate a viewController that is not in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Im currently using a custom `tabBarController` to navigate to my apps. I'm using storyboard for some of the view controllers and others Im not. the problem is that the `viewControllers` that are not in story are not being re instantiate. When I navigate to the view the first time everything work fine. If I exit and then come back the same view does not refresh. the same data is re-added on top of the old data. this happen to the views I could not add using an identifier to. The one i did `self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController` work fine. How can I solve this. Thank you in advance.

this work fine: this view behave normally because it was instantiate

```
 let dashboardController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DashboardViewController") as! DashboardViewController
        let dashboardTabImg = UIImage.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.User, textColor: iconColor, size: iconSize )
        let dashboardTabImgSelected = UIImage.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.User, textColor: iconColor, size: iconSize)
        dashboardController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Login", image: dashboardTabImg, selectedImage: dashboardTabImgSelected )


// this does not work properly because it was not instantiate.

     //receivePostRequest VC
            let receivePostRequest = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ReceivePostRequestViewController())
            let receivePostRequestImg = UIImage.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Dollar, textColor: iconColor, size: iconSize )
            let receivePostRequestImgSelected = UIImage.fontAwesomeIconWithName(.Dollar, textColor: iconColor, size: iconSize)
            receivePostRequest.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Request", image: receivePostRequestImg, selectedImage: receivePostRequestImgSelected )
```

//This is the viewController that is im having issues with

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ReceivePostRequestViewController: UIViewController {
   let receiveRequestSwitch = UISwitch()
    let receiveRequestLabel = UILabel()

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationItem.title = "Post Request"
        receiveRequestSwitch.isOn = false
        checkFirBaseForSwitchStatus()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        pageSetup()
        receiveRequestSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(postRequestSwitchButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

}
enum receivePostStatusEnums{

    case pending
    case accepted
    case disabled
    case declined
    case contactCustomerSupport
    case  error
}

extension ReceivePostRequestViewController {
    func pageSetup(){
        receiveRequestLabel.text = "Receive Post Request"
        receiveRequestLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        receiveRequestLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(receiveRequestLabel)
        receiveRequestLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
        receiveRequestLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 26).isActive = true
        receiveRequestLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -26).isActive = true
        receiveRequestLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true


        receiveRequestLabel.addSubview(receiveRequestSwitch)

        receiveRequestSwitch.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 44)
        receiveRequestSwitch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       // receiveRequestSwitch.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: receiveRequestLabel.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        receiveRequestSwitch.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: receiveRequestLabel.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        receiveRequestSwitch.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: receiveRequestLabel.centerYAnchor).isActive = true



    }
    func checkFirBaseForSwitchStatus(){


        FIRDatabase().childRef(refUrl: "frontEnd/users/\((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!)/receivePostRequest/info").observe(.value, with: {snapshot in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
                if let stat = dict["isAvailabileForRequest"] as? Bool {
                    if stat{
                        self.receiveRequestSwitch.isOn = true
                    }else{
                         self.receiveRequestSwitch.isOn = false
                    }
                }
            }else{
                self.receiveRequestSwitch.isOn = false
            }
        })
    }
    func postRequestSwitchButtonPressed(){
        if self.receiveRequestSwitch.isOn{
            receiveRequestSwitch.isOn = false
            let userId = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
            FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("frontEnd/users/\(userId!)/receivePostRequest/application").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snapshot in
                if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                            if let status = dict["status"] as? String {
                                print(status)
                                switch status {
                                    case "pending":
                                        print("its pending")
                                        self.simpleAlert(title: nil, message: "Your application is currently Being Reviewed, no action is required from you")

                                    case "accepted":
                                        print("its accepted")
                                        let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PostSelectViewController")
                                        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                    case "disabled":
                                        print("its disabled")
                                         self.simpleAlert(title: nil, message: "Your account is currently disabled if you have any questions please contact customer service")

                                    case "declined":
                                        self.simpleAlert(title: nil, message: "After reviewing your application we will not be able to continue your application we are very sorry. If you feel this was an error please contact our customer service")

                                    case "contactCustomerSupport":
                                        print("its contactCustomerSupport")
                                        self.simpleAlert(title: nil, message: "Please contact customer")

                                    case "error":
                                        print("its error")
                                          self.simpleAlert(title: nil, message: "We can not process your request please try again at a later time")

                                    default:
                                        print ("error")
                                          self.simpleAlert(title: nil, message: "We can not process your request please try again at a later time")
                                    }
                            }
                    return
                }
                //user need submit application here
                print("user need to fill out application page")
                let applicationNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController:ReceivePostRequestApplicationViewController())
                self.present(applicationNavController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            })
        }else{
            //update info to turn switch off
            FIRDatabase().childRef(refUrl: "frontEnd/users/\((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!)/receivePostRequest/info").updateChildValues(["isAvailabileForRequest":false], withCompletionBlock: { (error, fir) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                let ac = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "You will no longer receive service request", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (okAction) in
                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

                })
                ac.addAction(okAction)
                self.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil
                )

            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with how you create and setup your `ReceivePostRequestViewController`. Your issue has nothing to do with how it is created. You need to provide a lot more specific details about what issue you are having.

Comment: @rmaddy maybe when using a `tabBarController` it behave differently Im not sure, but when you exit a viewController and comeback to it the viewController should not save the previous data in memory.

Comment: You don't exit a view controller in a tab bar controller. You simply display a fixed set of controllers. If the user picks a different tab and then goes back to the previous tab, nothing new is created upon return. The user simply sees the existing view controller in that tab.

Comment: @rmaddy `instantiateWithIdentifier` does not give that issue. I also updated my question with the `ReceivePostRequestViewController` maybe i placed my functions in the wrong loading section of the viewController. I know the way around this is use storyboard but Im sure i would run into the same problem in the future.